# Specify MPI user

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, intel-mpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Configure MPI hostsfile to use multiple user identities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518314/configure-mpi-hostsfile-to-use-multiple-user-identities)

Does anyone know it is possible to specify the user which has to be used in an specific *ssh* connection with a given host or list of hosts in a MPI execution through *mpirun*? I need to use different users in different nodes.

Comment: I am running the Intel MPI implementation and it seems mpirun does not accept the -mca parameter

Comment: `--mca` is Open MPI specific parameter. You should have stated in your question that you use Intel MPI or you should have used the `intel-mpi` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found is to configure the *ssh* client by means of defining hosts and the proper users in the *~/.ssh/config* file, as explained [in this blog](http://mattryall.net/blog/2008/06/ssh-favourite-hosts) .